# Simple state machines. When does switch() beat if - else if - else

Tags: c, conditional-statements

***What guidelines can be followed when deciding between if - else if - else and switch - case?***

Some examples of equivalent couples of structures. Or are they?

```
int a;
#define const1 42
#define const2 666
```

---

```
if(a == const1){};

switch(a){  
    case const1: {} 
    break;  
}
```

---

```
if(a == const1){}
else {}

switch(a){  
    case const1: {} 
    break;  

    default: {}
    break;
}
```

---

```
if(a == const1){}
else if(a == const2){}
else {}

switch(a){  
    case const1: {} 
    break;  

    case const2: {} 
    break;  

    default: {}
    break;
}
```

From here on, I think switch is definitely superior in terms of both readability and performance.

As a matter of fact, I am currently at the last situation, trying to decide which way to go.

Comment: it's break and not brake

Comment: Generally when you have `enums` and want to check over them, you use `switch case`. The other case you have already described, too many `else if` conditions make the code less readable.

Comment: switch is always better since a loopup table is generated during compile time and its a matter of retreiving them. but dealing with c-strings?

Comment: @ Mohamed KALLEL, Probably I was thinking of bicycles! :D

Comment: @Koushik, I am strictly speaking about comparing with compile time constants. I am wandering at what size the table no longer provide advantage over the if. For a single condition, fro example?

Comment: What's efficient depends on many factors. Mostly on how smart the compiler is, what the target architecture can do, and how numerous and dense your constants are.

Comment: There should be **no performance difference at all** on a good compiler. A good compiler will implement `switch` and `if`/`else` in whatever way has the best performance, regardless of which syntax you choose.

Comment: well lets say there are 1000 cases and you write those if-else cases! then what would the compiler do? if using switch, it might use binary search,for example. what for if-else? same thing applies if compiler can be smart enough(well they surely are these days).

Comment: @Brendan Long, excuse me for the overly broad question. However, my querry includes non-optimizing compilers, not to mention unknown hardware. Besides, **readability** is an important factor.

Comment: @Vorac What I mean is that a `switch` statement is just syntactic sugar -- There's no reason for the compiler to treat it any differently than an `if`/`else` once it's parsed them. And yes, readability matters. My point is that it's the only thing you should consider here, because the compiled output will be exactly the same.

Comment: these things already have been discussed a dozen times, please search SO first. Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference in C and C++ between using if, else if, else if, ... and using switch () { case A: ... case B: ... }?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365341/is-there-any-difference-in-c-and-c-between-using-if-else-if-else-if-and)

Comment: @Koushik, nothing prevents the programmer to write the `if--else` as the optimal binary tree, considering the frequency of the values...

Comment: @BrendanLong, that very much depends on the compiler. E.g. [lcc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCC) does generate _very_ different code, and I suspect every compiler handles them differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they just involve evaluating a variable, testing it and executing a statement depending on that, there's no difference in the logic, and any decent compiler can see that.

I tried the same test (a check for `32`) with an `if` and a `switch`, and gcc, even with all optimisation turned off generated:

For the `if`:

```
movl    a(%rip), %eax
cmpl    $32, %eax
jne .L2
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L3
```

for the `switch`:

```
movl    a(%rip), %eax
cmpl    $32, %eax
jne .L6
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L3
```

Of course, if you're going to test the same integer for lots of values, a `switch` is more readable -- that's what it's intended for.

Comment: There exist application, that are (unfortunately) constrained to -O0 !

Comment: This was generated with `-O0`

Comment: Which is probably why he said "With all optimisation [sic] turned off"